# Reading in an oddly shaped HTML table to R

Tags: html, r, dataframe, html-table

I have an offline html file from some journal supplementary data. It is of a format where for one for one row/entry, some columns are split, for example:

```
OrganismID  GeneID

Org1        Gene1
____________
Org2        Gene1
            Gene2
___
Org3        Gene2
            Gene3
            Gene4
```

So for OrganismID the column has 3 rows, but the GeneID column has one row corresponding to the first row of OrganismID, 2 rows corresponding to the second row of OrganismID and three rows corresponding to the third row of OrganismID. So it looks like when you split cells in a table in a document. How can I get this into **R** and perhaps get it into a better format like a traditional **R** data.frame?

EDIT:

I've included the HTML code for the first few entries that nicely display how the columns of the table can have different rows. I'm not up and current on my HTML but they seem to "make room" for the multiple rows in the 4th 5th and 6th columns by defining it at the start of each row of column 1 by stating the `rowspan`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Overview per Gene</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Species</th>
<th>Gene ID</th>
<th>Length Upstream</th>
<th>Motif ID</th>
<th>Position</th>
<th>Strand</th>
<th>Match</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">P. infestans</td>
<td rowspan="2">PITG_00002</td>
<td rowspan="2">1000</td>
<td>Motif-0</td>
<td>-574</td>
<td>-</td>
<td>TCAGTCTTACATCTAC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Motif-1</td>
<td>-430</td>
<td>-</td>
<td>GTTACATGAAG</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="1">P. infestans</td>
<td rowspan="1">PITG_00004</td>
<td rowspan="1">454</td>
<td>Motif-1</td>
<td>-264</td>
<td>+</td>
<td>TACATGTAA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">P. infestans</td>
<td rowspan="2">PITG_00006</td>
<td rowspan="2">1000</td>
<td>Motif-0</td>
<td>-55</td>
<td>+</td>
<td>CATTCCTAATTTCGCC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Motif-1</td>
<td>-326</td>
<td>+</td>
<td>CATATATGTATGG</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="3">P. infestans</td>
<td rowspan="3">PITG_00009</td>
<td rowspan="3">1000</td>
<td>Motif-0</td>
<td>-413</td>
<td>-</td>
<td>TCACTTCTCTACTTTG</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Motif-1</td>
<td>-31</td>
<td>+</td>
<td>TACATGTAC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Motif-3</td>
<td>-271</td>
<td>-</td>
<td>TACTTGGAATTTGTAT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Comment: does this have standard HTML tags?

Comment: What does the source file look like?

Comment: I've included HTML sample which will both show 4 rows of the table in browser and demonstrate how it is constructed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made little corrections to your html code for example I've closed `<table>`, `<body>` and `<html>` and I have used `XML` package for reading this table. I noticed that in some cases columns are not in the right order, but you can fix after reading this table.

My proposition is below.

```
library(XML)

a<-'<html>
    <head>
    <title>Overview per Gene</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>Species</th>
    <th>Gene ID</th>
    <th>Length Upstream</th>
    <th>Motif ID</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Strand</th>
    <th>Match</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">P. infestans</td>
    <td rowspan="2">PITG_00002</td>
    <td rowspan="2">1000</td>
    <td>Motif-0</td>
    <td>-574</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>TCAGTCTTACATCTAC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Motif-1</td>
    <td>-430</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>GTTACATGAAG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td rowspan="1">P. infestans</td>
    <td rowspan="1">PITG_00004</td>
    <td rowspan="1">454</td>
    <td>Motif-1</td>
    <td>-264</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>TACATGTAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">P. infestans</td>
    <td rowspan="2">PITG_00006</td>
    <td rowspan="2">1000</td>
    <td>Motif-0</td>
    <td>-55</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>CATTCCTAATTTCGCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Motif-1</td>
    <td>-326</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>CATATATGTATGG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">P. infestans</td>
    <td rowspan="3">PITG_00009</td>
    <td rowspan="3">1000</td>
    <td>Motif-0</td>
    <td>-413</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>TCACTTCTCTACTTTG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Motif-1</td>
    <td>-31</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>TACATGTAC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Motif-3</td>
    <td>-271</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>TACTTGGAATTTGTAT</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>'

doc<-htmlParse(a)
tab<-readHTMLTable(doc,which=1)
idx<-which(is.na(tab$Match))
lapply(tab,class)
for (i in 1:ncol(tab)){
  tab[,i]<-as.character(tab[,i])
}
tab[idx,c(4:7)]<-tab[idx,c(1:4)]
tab[idx,c(1:3)]<-NA
```

and result

```
tab
       Species    Gene ID Length Upstream Motif ID Position Strand            Match
1 P. infestans PITG_00002            1000  Motif-0     -574      - TCAGTCTTACATCTAC
2         <NA>       <NA>            <NA>  Motif-1     -430      -      GTTACATGAAG
3 P. infestans PITG_00004             454  Motif-1     -264      +        TACATGTAA
4 P. infestans PITG_00006            1000  Motif-0      -55      + CATTCCTAATTTCGCC
5         <NA>       <NA>            <NA>  Motif-1     -326      +    CATATATGTATGG
6 P. infestans PITG_00009            1000  Motif-0     -413      - TCACTTCTCTACTTTG
7         <NA>       <NA>            <NA>  Motif-1      -31      +        TACATGTAC
8         <NA>       <NA>            <NA>  Motif-3     -271      - TACTTGGAATTTGTAT
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to close the tabs, the snippet I provided is just the first 4 rows, it goes on for over 1,000 pages printed on A4. This definitely looks along the lines of what I think I need. I'll try it and come back.